# Web Browsers do not always render between tasks added to Macrotask queue (using setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout, requestanimationframe

I thought the Javascript Event loop is meant to execute tasks in Macrotask queue in similar way across web browsers. In short simplified way (not considering evaluating script, microtask queue, etc.):

1. *take the oldest task from Macrotask queue and run it*
2. *render*
3. *repeat*

I'm facing inconsistency in *Chrome* whereas *Firefox* for example seems much more consistent in following the before mentioned steps.

## Example

Here's the >silly< code **example** to demonstrate the issue:

**index.html**

```html
...
<head>
<script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
...
```

**index.js**

```js
"use strict";

function sleep(ms)
{
    const start = performance.now();
    while ((performance.now() - start) < ms);
}

function doNextPart()
{
    currentPart++;
    sleep(20);
    addToRender(currentPart.toString());
}

function addToRender(part)
{
    partsList.push(part);
}

function render(timestamp)
{
    frame++;
    console.log(`frame: ${frame} \t rendering time: ${timestamp}`);

    for (const part of partsList)
    {
        const itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
        itemDiv.innerHTML = `part: ${part} || frame: ${frame}, ${timestamp}`;
        partsContainerDiv.appendChild(itemDiv);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(partsContainerDiv);

    partsList.length = 0;
    if (frame <= 5)
    {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
}

const partsContainerDiv = document.createElement("div");
const partsList = [];
let frame = 0;
let currentPart = 0;

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

setTimeout(doNextPart);
setTimeout(doNextPart);
setTimeout(doNextPart);
```

Here's a bit of **explanation** :

- `requestAnimationFrame()` is used to render : what is currently in the `partsList` array and then clears that array, current `frame` number, `timestamp`
- `doNexPart()` function : is just blocking the *event loop* for given time using `sleep()` function, then adding a 'result' (`currentPart`) to the `partsList` array for rendering
- loop stops after 5 frames
- it's adding the `doNextPart()` function to the *Macrotask queue* three times
- ( `console.log()` is used to log all (*5*) frames - mainly for the last frames timestamp with no task from Macrotask queue )

Here's what I **expect**:

- take a task from *Macrotask queue* => first `doNextPart()` is ran, it adds "1" as a 'result' to the `partsList` array
- *render* => Event loop is now able to render calling the `render()` function, so the HTML output is

  `part: 1 || frame: 1`
- *repeat*

#### Firefox

I expect the **final HTML output** should be something like this:

`part: 1 || frame: 1`

`part: 2 || frame: 2`

`part: 3 || frame: 3`

- This above is what I get **in** ***Firefox*** almost all the time.
- The first three frames took about **25ms** each `sleep(20ms)` and the other two took about **8ms** (5 frames in total).

**In other words** - it renders between tasks because it tries to render at a ratio usually given by the display refresh rate (let's say each **8ms** for 120Hz) - in (an)other words *Firefox* tries to follow the steps.

#### Chrome

But **in** ***Chrome*** the HTML output is:

`part: 1 || frame: 2`

`part: 2 || frame: 2`

`part: 3 || frame: 2`

So it's rendered all at once in **one frame** and that frame took **91.7 ms**.

When I look at Performance tab the tasks are executed as they should but the paint is done only after last one.

**But when** the time passed to `sleep()` function is **high enough** (*100ms* works for me) ***Chrome*** renders **as expected.**

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Chrome version tested: 110.0.5481.178

Firefox version tested: 110.0.1

Main sources:

[Exploring ES6](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_async.html)

[JavaScript Visualizer](https://www.jsv9000.app/?code=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%3D%3D)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Question

What I'm after is:

- am I doing something terribly wrong here
- is this behaviour normal or is it kind of a bug
- shouldn't we expect the same behaviour in browsers handling macrotask queue or not

Comment: FWIW, I get completely different results on both Firefox and Chrome. No time to dig into what you're doing right now, but here are a few notes at first glance: Never test how the event loop and particularly setTimeout and rAF, work form the page's loading. Browsers have a lot of special rules in that particular phase. For instance, Firefox uses a special task-queue, with lower priority, just for timeouts that have been made during the page load. Also, avoid `setTimeout` to test "fast" macrotasks. Chrome still has a 1ms minimum delay. Prefer the scheduler API when available, or postMessage

Comment: The first call to `requestAnimationFrame` from a non-animated document is executed as soon as possible in both Firefox and Chrome, i.e it won't wait for the next V-Sync. To avoid that particular case, you may want to start a dummy rAF loop that does nothing but call rAF. However, as you can see, all these would just make for another fake testing environment, so it's not clear if that would clarify anything for you, because that's what it is: browsers use a lot of different rules in different situations which make the behavior in real execution unpredictable without knowing said  real execution

Comment: @Kaiido Appreciate your answer.
With the page's loading - I see that, I delayed the start of the script, I did the 'dummy rAF loop' but I still get the rendering phase not following the execution of the single task.
I understand that browsers do much more than the simple abstraction of the event loop, and as you said different things in different situations, and that this is probably not the best test case and we have better tools for scheduling tasks, but still - shouldn't they follow the simple steps: one task from Macrotask queue then render (and not blocking it)?